# Folder issues with Tomcat 7 on Ubuntu

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu

I've installed Tomcat 7 on Ubuntu 14.04. The main problem is with two different folders which are sometimes redundant:

**/usr/share/tomcat7**

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 dic 15  2013 backup
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 set  3 13:28 bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 nov 17  2013 conf -> /var/lib/tomcat7/conf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   39 feb 21  2014 defaults.md5sum
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2030 feb 21  2014 defaults.template
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 set  3 13:28 lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 nov 17  2013 log -> /var/log/tomcat7
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   53 feb 21  2014 logrotate.md5sum
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  118 feb 21  2014 logrotate.template
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 dic  2 13:00 logs
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 dic  6 17:33 webapps
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 dic 15  2013 work
drwxrwxrwx 5 root root 4096 dic  2 13:16 wtpwebapps
```

**/var/lib/tomcat7**

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 nov 16  2013 common
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root    root      12 mag 24  2013 conf -> /etc/tomcat7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root    root      17 mag 24  2013 logs -> ../../log/tomcat7
drwxr-xr-x 3 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 nov 16  2013 server
drwxr-xr-x 3 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 nov 16  2013 shared
drwxrwxr-x 4 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 dic  6 23:51 webapps
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root    root      19 mag 24  2013 work -> ../../cache/tomcat7
```

When I installed packages such as `tomcat7-docs`, `tomcat7-examples` and `tomcat7-admins`, they were automatically deployed under `/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps`. Also Eclipse, when the option "Use Tomcat installation" is selected, automatically deploys the files under `/usr/share/tomcat7/wtpwebapps`.

However, if I have to deploy a web app of mine, I've to put it under `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps`;  I don't know if it is right, maybe yes, but why?
Also, when I look at the log files generated when launching my web apps, tomcat complains about some folders that do not exists; indeed, they exists only under `/var/lib/tomcat7` and not under `/usr/share/tomcat7`.

```
Dec 06, 2014 11:50:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Dec 06, 2014 11:50:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Dec 06, 2014 11:50:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Dec 06, 2014 11:50:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Dec 06, 2014 11:50:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Dec 06, 2014 11:50:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
```

So, what I've to change to make all works? Is this folder structure desiderable?

Answer (score 6):

Those 2 directories are used by tomcat to allow configuration of multiple tomcat instances all using a single installation directory but each having its own directories for deployment, logs, conf, etc.

Tomcat uses the following environment variables (or system properties) to specify the 2 directory locations:

> CATALINA_HOME (catalina.home), the tomcat install directory and
>   CATALINA_BASE (catalina.base), the base directory for a tomcat instance

Some tomcat installations use the same directory for both catalina.base and catalina.home and that's the default behavior if `CATALINA_BASE` is not set.

Given the Ubuntu 14.04 tomcat7 configuraion of:

> catalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat7
>   catalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat7

You should deploy applications to `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps`.  The only time apps should be deployed to `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps` is if `catalina.base=catalina.home.`  Installation of tomcat7 on my **Ubuntu 14.04** didn't even create a /usr/share/tocmat7/webapps.

The reason I found your post is that I recently installed tomcat7 and encountered the same "Problem with directory" warnings that you are getting:

> **WARNING**: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]

The warning are the result the `common.loader`, `server.loader`, and `shared.loader` entires in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties.`  As they should be, the common, server, and shared directories are under `$CATALINA_BASE`.

I eliminated the warnings by changing each `*.loader= entry` to use `catalina.base` rather than `catalina.home` for those directories (6 places).

Answer (score 5):

I think there is a better answer.

As stated here : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomcat7/+bug/1308284
and here : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomcat7/+bug/1232258, here is the best way to solve this (works in more scenarios, especially when you use tomcat7-user package) :

```
cd /usr/share/tomcat7
sudo ln -s /var/lib/tomcat7/common/ common
sudo ln -s /var/lib/tomcat7/server/ server
sudo ln -s /var/lib/tomcat7/shared/ shared
```

and maybe not necessary :

```
sudo ln -s /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/ conf
sudo ln -s /var/lib/tomcat7/logs/ logs
sudo mkdir /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
```